# Test for Items in chest?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to use a command block to test for 3 unnamed nether stars in the first slot of a regular chest. I've searched the internet but I can't find any working commands (I'm on 1.10)

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: as I said above I searched the internet. but that's about all I can do seance I don't have experience when it comes to commands

Comment: We generally expect you to try to figure it out, first.  Even if you can't do it, showing us you tried is extremely helpful.

Comment: the part I'm stuck at is finding a command, see when I go looking for commands for my maps I search the internet, I had found 1 but it was for an older version the block was saying "unknown command search help for list of commands

Comment: that and I don't know what type of command block to use

Comment: You get help when you get it.  How soon you get it will depend on who's on, how clear your question is, and how receptive answerers see your question.  The best way you can help yourself here is to add more details of what you're trying to do, and what you've done yourself.

Comment: 1. Is it important that this only tests for unnamed stars, or would it be fine if it detects stars with a name? 2. Will any stars ever have lore text?

Answer (score 0):

You could use /testforblock on a chest with the unique data structure in the 'NBT Data' slot of the command.